# Trying to upgrade Singelton to get accurately two instances of one object

Tags: java, singleton

I like to upgrade the `Singleton` pattern to get 2 intances.

This is what I have tried:

```
public class Singelton_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singelton odellBeckhamJr = Singelton.getIntance();
    }
}

class Singelton {   
    private static Singelton obj;
    private Singelton() { }  
    public static Singelton getIntance() {
        if (obj == null) {
            obj = new Singelton();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

But so far I did not succeed. Can you help me?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I like to change the code to get two instances

Comment: Are you inventing a `Doubleton`?

Comment: Hi @Chris, the concept of Singleton is to have one instance only of that object throughout your application, which is what your code has been doing.  Kindly elaborate what you want to achieve so we can help

Comment: Yes I just want a Doubleton, to make sure that its only possible to create two instances.

Comment: thats interesting for my next exam

Comment: And which one do you want to return by `getInstance()`? Or are you planning to provide something like `public static Singleton[]  getInstances()`?

Comment: This isn't even a correct singleton.

Comment: whats wrong with that?

Comment: A "doubleton" doesn't make any sense. A singleton object is a single object that is used throughout your application. A "doubleton" would do what? Create two new instances? So what this class is instantiated, which object should be returned? Please explain your question properly.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would recommend to instantiate the singleton instance at class creation:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
        // hide constructor
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This guarantees thread-safe instantiation of the instance. If Just-in-Time is needed, [proper double-checked locking (scroll down to "Under the new Java Memory Model")](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) can be used.

If two instances should be created (i.e. a special form of the [Multiton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)), I would recommend to replicate the above solution:

```
public class Doubleton {
    private static final Doubleton INSTANCE_ONE = new Doubleton();
    private static final Doubleton INSTANCE_TWO = new Doubleton();
    private static final List<Doubleton> INSTANCES = List.of(INSTANCE_ONE, INSTANCE_TWO);

    private Doubleton() {
        // hide constructor
    }

    public static Doubleton getInstanceOne() {
        return INSTANCE_ONE;
    }

    public static Doubleton getInstanceTwo() {
        return INSTANCE_TWO;
    }

    public static List<Doubleton> getInstances() {
        return INSTANCES;
    }
}
```

[`List<E> of(E e1, E e2,)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E)) require Java in version 9 or higher.

[Andy's answer utilizing `Enum`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57127169/4216641) provides an interesting alternative.

Comment: Thanks you Turing85!

Comment: @Rick jep, thanks for the heads up. I have corrected the typo. My comment will self-destruct shortly.

Comment: Double-checked locking is hard to implement correctly (there is even a typo in its implementation in Effective Java 3rd Ed). Lazy holder is substantially simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.

The `singleton` pattern has been designed to get you exactly 1 instance of the object. Altering it, will likely cause issues. Besides, you won't need it.

If you want a "double singleton", just create a singleton containing 2 objects in a unmutable list or array. You can return this list from a function on your singleton if you like.

You might even call it a `factory`, this singleton object provider.

---

So, as it seems, something slightly different will be called a `multiton`... ^^^ see @Turing85's answer above

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest way to limit the number of instances is with an enum:

```
enum Doubleton {
  INSTANCE1, INSTANCE2
 }
```

This is resistant even to reflective creation of instances, so there are guaranteed only ever to be two instances.

---

If you want to lazily instantiate the instances, the easiest approach is the [lazy holder idiom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), which :

```
class Doubleton {
  private Doubleton() {}

  static Doubleton instance1() {
    return Holder1.X;
  }

  static Doubleton instance2() {
    return Holder2.X;
  }

  private static class Holder1 {
    static final Doubleton X = new Doubleton();
  }

  private static class Holder2 {
    static final Doubleton X = new Doubleton();
  }
}
```

But you should carefully evaluate whether lazy initialization is really a required property.

Comment: Only downside: You have no posibility for Just-in-Time instantiation. Otherwise, this is an interesting usecase for an `Enum` I have not considered up until now.

Comment: @Turing85 you have exactly the same possibility of just-in-time instantiation as with static final fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put a static counter in the constructor to count how many objects have been created of this class. If you want to create only two then put a check of two, after two counts, you just return old objects.

Comment: Without proper synchronization, this will lead to problems in a multithreaded environment. In general, I would advice against Just-in-Time creation of the instances.

Comment: Yes, correct.@Turing85